# Dictionary Combinations - Unequal Number of Keys & Values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I want to print all unique combinations of keys and values for this dictionary:

```
items = {'a':[10,100,1000],'b':[11,110],'c':[12,120]}
```

Using the code,

```
for key, value in items.items():
    print(key,value)
```

I receive the following output:

```
b [11, 110]
c [12, 120]
a [10, 100, 1000]
```

I would like to produce the following result given the dictionary:

```
b 11
b 110
c 12
c 120
a 10
a 100
a 1000
```

Order of the key-value combinations is not important, but the result should preserve the relationship.  As always, any recommended resources and/or search terms associated with this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close:

```
items = {'a':[10,100,1000],'b':[11,110],'c':[12,120]}

# iterate on key/items couple
for k,vl in items.items():
    # iterate on all values of the list
    for v in vl:
        # print with a simple format
        print("{} {}".format(k,v))
```

output:

```
a 10
a 100
a 1000
c 12
c 120
b 11
b 110
```

Note that you can use `for k,vl in sorted(items.items()):` to print the keys in the sorted order `(a,b,c)`, same goes for the inside list:

```
# iterate on key/items couple
for k,vl in sorted(items.items()):
    # iterate on all values of the list
    for v in sorted(vl):
        # print with a simple format
        print("{} {}".format(k,v))
```

output:

```
a 10
a 100
a 1000
b 11
b 110
c 12
c 120
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jean-Francois.  I want to learn more about this technique, would you consider this a nested for loop?  (I will be accepting your response as an answer ASAP).

Comment: A nested for loop is a for loop inside another for loop.  This qualifies.

Answer (score 2):

Or simply :

```
items = {'a':[10,100,1000],'b':[11,110],'c':[12,120]}

for key, value in items.items():
    for v in value :
        print(key,v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterables`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), you can "flatten" this to a list of tuples:

```
In [27]: import itertools

In [28]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(item_[0], v) for v in item_[1]] for item_ in items.items()]))
Out[28]: 
[('a', 10),
 ('a', 100),
 ('a', 1000),
 ('c', 12),
 ('c', 120),
 ('b', 11),
 ('b', 110)]
```

From this, it's easy to do anything you want like printing it:

```
In [29]: for k, v in itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(item_[0], v)     for v in item_[1]] for item_ in items.items()]):
   ....:     print k, v
   ....:     
a 10
a 100
a 1000
c 12
c 120
b 11
b 110
```